# asp.net httpmodule execution order

Tags: asp.net

Does the order of httpmodule execution match their order in the web.config or is it undefinied?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427451/how-is-the-order-of-execution-for-httpmodules-determined : order is same as in web.config but you shouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they seem to be fired in the order that they are in the web.config but if possible try not to depend on having a particular order as this can introduce problems to your app because of dependencies