# Session is null in the new page when transfer the request in the HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, session, httpmodule

All, I'm trying to implement an HttpModule (IHttpModule) to catch pages request and redirect to a new page. Unfortunately, it seems I can't use the `Session` in the new page. because the `Session` is null.

Here is my code looks like. please review it .

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);

        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ....
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("newpage.aspx");//redirect to new page.
        }
}
```

In the `newpage.aspx`, There is an exception says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` for the code `HttpContext.Current.Session[xxx]`, Because the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null .
Could someone tell me what happen to it ?
Thanks.

**Update**

All, I found If I use the `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` to redirect url . Everything is ok. I mean the `Session` object is initiated before being used.But that doesn't work for `Server.Transfer`.

I already knew what is the difference of these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect).

Comment: Can you show the URL of the first and the second page? You can probably going to a seperate domain of to a diffrent protocol.

Comment: @peer Both of them are in the same app. the urls look like from `http://localhost:7778/orginalpage.aspx` redirect to `http://localhost:7778/b/c/newpage.aspx`. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The normal aspx runtime pipeline with 2 modules is:

```
--> HttpModule_1.BeginRequest();  --> HttpModule_2.BeginRequest(); --> HttpHandler(Page)
<-- HttpModule_1.EndRequest();  <-- HttpModule_2.EndRequest(); <-- HttpHandler(Page)
```

Imagine HttpModule_1 as your custom module and HttpModule_2 as the aspx session module.

Your custom module is running first, so no session is filled in when your module is running.

When HttpModule_1 is running BeginRequest you add a Server.Trasfer(). Now, the server transfer will execute the HttpHandler of the request page immediately, it will be called without leaving the BeginRequest and after the handler is done the transfer method will run the Request.End() and terminate the processing.

So, the handler for the "newpage.aspx" will also run before the session module. (actually, the session module will never run because Server.Transfer() will end the request).

If you guaranty that the session module is processes before your module you should resolve the problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427632/953144).