# SSO lags behind the HTTP Module I user for security in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, httpmodule

We currently have an HTTP Module in our assorted web (mostly web forms) applications that handles authentication, page access, and menu construction. We are trying to introduce SSO, but are finding that we cannot predict the order in which modules (or their events) execute.  As a result, the Request Header values that SSO populates (such as username)http are often populated after our Security module initially executes.

I would hate to move the code to the master pages.  Or, I guess more accurately, into a class called by the master pages, but I don't see another reasonable option. I need something that fires AFTER SSO does its thing.

I am looking for an alternative to using a module. Something that still provides a generally centralized passthrough/hub for controlling traffic.  The only thing I have been able to come up with is a master page call, which does not let me manage non-aspx resources, but it may be the best I can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the order of execution for HttpModules determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427451/how-is-the-order-of-execution-for-httpmodules-determined)

Comment: I have moved way past the point where I am trying to dictate the execution order of modules. That isn't going to happen.  I am looking for an alternative to using a module, but something that still provides a generally centralized passthrough/hub for controlling traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to solve the wrong problem. I was trying to make the *current* Security HTTPModule work in conjunction with SSO (Siteminder).  The problem was that the existing code was designed at a time that it was both the authenticator of user identity and the authorizer of resource requests based on that identity.  Not that we are giving up that first role, we have to move our authorization code into the appropriate event -- after SSO has set the request values -- `PostAcquireRequestState`. Placing the authorization code there solves all of our problems.  To misquote the Bard, the fault is not in the code, but in ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't coax your modules to execute in order via config, you can force them to execute in order via code.

First, remove the problem modules from config.

Then, add a single new module to config. You will have to write this module. The module should call the other modules in the desired order. For example:

```
class MyModuleChain : IHttpModule
{
    private IHttpModule _module1 = new Module1();
    private IHttpModule _module2 = new Module2();

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {  
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Application_BeginRequest);
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(Application_EndRequest);
    }

    public void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call the modules in a fixed order
        _module1.Application_BeginRequest(source, e);
        _module2.Application_BeginRequest(source, e);
    }

    public void Application_EndRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call the modules in a fixed order
        _module1.Application_EndRequest(source, e);
        _module2.Application_EndRequest(source, e);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _module1.Dispose();
        _module2.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You may have to implement more event handlers if they are needed by the dependent modules.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, John.  I wonder if that would force synchronous-ness onto something that IIS handles asynchronously. I will sleep on it.  Thanks for the thought.